# display User Entity SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I work with symfony 2.8 and sonataAdminBundle, in the BackOffice I like to see two type of users "Client" and "Correspondant" , this two users have the same Entity "User" and I have differenciate this two user by a field "type" , I have create to AdminClasse like this :

**CorrespondantAdmin**

```
 class CorrespondantAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
  {
      public function createQuery($context = 'list')
       {
          $query = parent::createQuery($context);
          $query->andWhere(
          $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAliases()[0] . '.type', ':my_param')
     );
         $query->setParameter('my_param', 'correspondant');
       return $query;

      }

     protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)

       {
           $listMapper

       ->addIdentifier('nom')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('civilite')
        ->add('dateInscrit')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
            )
        ))

         ;

      }
```

**ClientAdmin**

```
 class ClientAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
  {
      public function createQuery($context = 'list')
       {
          $query = parent::createQuery($context);
          $query->andWhere(
          $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAliases()[0] . '.type', ':my_param')
     );
         $query->setParameter('my_param', 'client');
       return $query;

      }

     protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)

       {
           $listMapper

       ->addIdentifier('nom')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('civilite')
        ->add('dateInscrit')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
            )
        ))

         ;

      }
```

**Admin.yml**

```
    app.admin.correspondant:
    class: Devagnos\AdminBundle\Admin\CorrespondantAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Utilisateurs", label: "Mes Correspondants" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Devagnos\UserBundle\Entity\User
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AdminBundle]]
    public: true

app.admin.client:
    class: Devagnos\AdminBundle\Admin\ClientAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Utilisateurs", label: "Mes Clients" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Devagnos\UserBundle\Entity\User
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AdminBundle]]
    public: true
```

the problem that I have always the result of the last service declared (in this issue the result is always the "client" in the view of "Client" and of the "Correspondant"

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you clear the cache? Is your Admin.yml properly formatted?

**Edit:**
You probably have same route for both admin classes. Try define own route for each admin. After that clear cache.

**ClientAdmin**

```
class ClientAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    const ROUTE = 'client-user';

    protected $baseRoutePattern = self::ROUTE;

    protected $baseRouteName = self::ROUTE;


    ...
```

**CorrespondantAdmin**

```
class CorrespondantAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    const ROUTE = 'correspondant-user';

    protected $baseRoutePattern = self::ROUTE;

    protected $baseRouteName = self::ROUTE;


    ...
```